# Tree Map iteration (Column as Key<String> and Rows as List<String>) is skipping rows with Entry Set option

Tags: java, iterator, treemap

**Input**

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 |

Captured as **TreeMap<String, List> map**

Key is Column Name (ColumnA)
Each row is List Values.

I want to retrieve the information like this.

**Itration 1:**
ColumnA -->Cell1
ColumnB --> Cell2

**Itration** 2:
ColumnA -->Cell3
ColumnB --> Cell3

and so on........

````
TreeMap<String, List<String>> map
                    = new TreeMap<String, List<String>>();

for (int j = 0; j < tcols; j++) {
                List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
                for (int i = 1; i < rows.getCount(); i++) {
                    String s = convertNumberToString(cells.get(i, j).getValue().toString());
                    list.add(s);
                }
                String colHeader = cells.get(0, j).getValue().toString();
                map.put(colHeader, list);
            }

            iterateMapRowWise(map);

    public static void iterateMapRowWise(TreeMap<String, List<String>> map) {
        int maxListSize = 0;
        for (List<String> values : map.values()) {
            maxListSize = Math.max(maxListSize, values.size());

        }
        System.out.println(maxListSize);
        //list size iteration
        for (int i = 0; i < maxListSize; i++) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                String key = entry.getKey();
                List<String> values = entry.getValue();
                   System.out.println(" ::"+i+" ::"+key + " ::" + values.get(i));
            }
        }

    }```

Iteration is happening with Column name as Key and List<String> of iteration number as value.
However, the data is not iterating from the Zeroth row but rather random as below.

some values are truncated at the beginning and start with some random iteration.

trans_idfr_org_unit ::1000
trans_idfr_orgnl ::null
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>**IterationCount :: 271**  >>>>>>>>>>>>
aba_nmbr ::null
accrl_status ::null
acct_invld_ind ::null
acct_status_chng_mode ::null
acct_status_chng_revrsl_mode ::null


**Expected**:

**>>>>>>>>>>>>>>**IterationCount :: 1**  >>>>>>>>>>>>
**aba_nmbr ::row1Value
accrl_status ::row1Value
acct_invld_ind ::row1Value
acct_status_chng_mode ::row1Value
acct_status_chng_revrsl_mode ::row1Value
**>>>>>>>>>>>>>>**IterationCount :: 2**  >>>>>>>>>>>>
**aba_nmbr ::row2Value
accrl_status ::row2Value
acct_invld_ind ::row2Value
acct_status_chng_mode ::row2Value
acct_status_chng_revrsl_mode ::row2Value
````